# Transfer a JSON string between programs without saving a file

Tags: python, json, transfer

Let's assume I have two Python modules, `first.py` and `second.py`. `first.py` generates a JSON string; `second.py` takes a JSON string and does subsequent processes. To simplify them, consider the example written below:

```
# first.py
import json
fruit = input("Name a fruit: ")
material_str = json.dumps({"fruit": fruit})
print(material_str)

# second.py
import json
material = json.loads(material_str)
def blender(material):
    serving = material["fruit"] + " juice"
    return serving
print(blender(material))
```

Now my problem is: how to transfer `material_str` from `first.py` to `second.py`? Is there a way to make `material_str` somehow cached in the memory and then taken by `second.py` (or even more general, by programs in other languages which can load JSON strings)? Because it seems unlikely that the `print`ed string can be transferred like this.

I know I can `json.dump` the dictionary into a file in `first.py`, and `json.load` it in `second.py`. However, these codes will be executed thousands of times a day and the JSON strings are useful only during the execution, so I don't want to save them. Combining `first.py` and `second.py` is not feasible either because in fact they are two big projects developed by different people. In fact, consider `first.py` as a script doing OCR and `second.py` as a script of one iOS app. Now the results of OCR need to be transferred to the app script so that they can be presented.

I have read some documentation about `sys.stdout` but it looks like no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about sharing a memory resource between two different processes? Otherwise this question doesn't make a lot of sense (You could share a global variable, send it to a function or many other methods..).

Comment: @Rohi Consider `first.py` as a script doing OCR and `second.py` as a script of one iOS app. Now the results of OCR need to be transferred to the app script so that they can be presented.

Comment: how are they supposed to be "transferred" ? Where is the first script running, where is the second script running ?

Comment: Who manages these scripts? Are they two independent threads, or does the iOS app call the OCR script?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers `first.py` runs on a Linux server, while the second script is an iOS app. Is this what you meant by "where"?

Comment: And how do the iOS app and the process on the linux server communicate ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Through another API of `first.py` maybe? So the problem is still "How to transfer the json string so that the other script/program can catch it?".

Comment: If you don't know how your process are supposed to communicate then it's just plain impossible to answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers If I don't know how the results can be possibly transferred then how am I supposed to know how they are going to communicate...?

Comment: You need to work out **how** your systems are going to communicate before working out **what** they will communicate

Comment: @ytu if you don't have a clue on how an iOS app (or and android one fwiw) can communicate with a distant server then you have a problem indeed. Perhaps reading about IPCs might help ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: Oh and yes: this is really not a python question - the fact that the json is generated by a Python script is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is totally solvable in Python. In my case, the only thing I need is testing whether the JSON string can be transferred across programs without saving a file, like I indicated in the title.

What I need is `subprocess` module in second.py to execute first.py in a subprocess, and then pipe the results for subsequent procedures.

```
import json
import subprocess
import re
# Get stdout from first.py
raw_result = subprocess.run(["python", "first.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# Capture the JSON string
material_str = re.search(r".+({.+})", str(raw_result.stdout)).group(1)
# Load the JSON string as a dictionary
material = json.loads(material_str)
# Make juice
def blender(material):
    serving = material["fruit"] + " juice"
    return serving
print(blender(material))
```

By executing `python second.py` and entering "Apple", it returns "Apple juice" perfectly.